# Find minimum solubilty of AgCN

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, solubility, concentration

[image]

i know it has to be solved by writing an equation between CN- conc and solubilty but i am unable to write a non-linear equation,any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Option C is the right answer
Solubility of AgCN will be equal to sum of concentrations of  Ag+ and [Ag(CN)2]-
[image: Detailed answer]

Comment: Now I get it, rereading the q.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Could you tell me where I am going wrong with the this approach? Let the  initial concentration of $\ce{AgCN}$ be $x$, so we write $$\ce{\underbrace{AgCN}_{initially x} <=> Ag+ + CN-}$$ and so concentration of $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{CN-}$ would become $y$, and that of $\ce{AgCN}$ be $x-y$. Now, we write $$\ce{Ag+ + 2 CN- <=> [Ag(CN)_2]-}$$ And if now $z$ amound reacts in this reaction, we get the final concentrations of $\ce{Ag+}$ as $y-z$, of $\ce{CN-}$ as $y-2z$ and that of $\ce{[Ag(CN)_2]-}$ as $z$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: So that we have from the $\ce{K_\text{sp}}$ equation, $(y-z)(y-2z)=10^{-16}$ and from the $\ce{K_f}$ equation, $\dfrac{z}{(y-z)(y-2z)^2}=1.5 \times 10^{17}$, but this would yield 2 equations and 2 variables and hence a unique value for the concentration of $\ce{CN-}$, but we want the minimum value of $y$... so what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: @Light Yagami Check this
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7r8tvfytgw

Comment: @Govind What do you want to convey by that? There are two solutions as I said, but one would yield negative values hence discarded but the one with positive values is legible, right? See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7B%28y-x%29%28y-2x%29%3D10%5E%28-16%29%2C+%28y-x%29%28y-2x%29%5E2%3Dx%2F%281.5*10%5E%2817%29%29+%7D). What I wanted to ask is, what is wrong with this approach as this yields an exact solution, whereas I should have gotten an algebraic expression in which I would have to minimize $y$. But here I am getting a value of $y$ from the equations itself!

Comment: Actually the question conveys a different thing. The CN- concentration can be varied by us so as to get the maximum solubility of AgCN.